# Live Ever Changing Updating List in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new in python and it seems that after searching all over I can't seem to find a solution for this. So what I'm trying to do is have a blank list with nothing in it then have a variable that appends data that is always changing per day to that list. What I wanted to have is how do you update the list of changes like that happen. I'll try to explain it in this code

```
l = []
sum = data[0][1]
l.append(sum)
```

Now, this sum variable value is always changing every day or every second just like taking data from a JSON File that is constantly being updated. What I want to do is that the list just wouldn't change but adds the ever-changing sum each time it changes so if sum = 1 on the first day and then sum = 2 on the second day I want the list to be updated so it would be [1] on the first day then [1,2] on the second day. I'm really confused about which part of python I should learn just to be able to do this if anyone has any suggestions it would really help for my first project in python. Thank you.

Comment: So you want some data to be appended to the list every day?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: btw don't use `list` as the name of a variable. It is already used as a bult-in.

Comment: @DevanshSoni yes exactly although im maybe wrong into using list as a variable name sorry

Comment: If you want to store the values in a list and append a new value to it every day, It's practically impossible because our programs run in RAM, and all the variables you create are stored in RAM and vanishes as soon as program's execution stops. So, to achieve this, you've to create a file and store the values in the file and append a new value to it every day. To add new values to the file every day, you should use a Job scheduler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for use of a loop. Here is an example using an infinite loop (`while True`).

```py
import time  # for "waiting" a day

N_SEC_IN_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24  # 1 day in seconds
list_ = []
while True:
    sum_ = getsum()  # defined elsewhere
    list_.append(sum_)
    time.sleep(N_SEC_IN_DAY)
```

Also, note the several **stylistic** changes I made.

- `list` -> `list_` to avoid clashes with built-in functions.
- `sum` -> `sum_` to avoid clashes with built-in functions.

If you want to access this list while the program is running, you might want to add a logger that logs the values in `list_` every time a new `sum_`is added.

Add the following lines to the top of your code:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='log', level=logging.INFO)
```

Add change the loop to say:

```py
while True:
    sum_ = getsum()  # defined elsewhere
    list_.append(sum_)
    logging.info(str(list))  # LOGGING TAKES PLACE HERE
    time.sleep(N_SEC_IN_DAY)
```

Finally, I would like to point out that a better way to do this would be to use crontabs to schedule jobs. I'm not going to go in-depth about that because there are plenty of tutorials online, just google "crontab." (Thanks to commenter DevanshSoni for the reminder.)

Comment: One has to keep his machine running for an infinite time to implement this. This is the most impractical way to do it.

Comment: That's what's being asked, though, no?

Comment: @DevanshSoni, okay, well I added a small note at the end addressing your comment, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say. One can't keep his machine running all the time and that's why we use Crontabs for job scheduling.

Comment: @ThomasBreydo Hi i was wondering if you can store that list in txt or something because for all i know an appended data wouldnt work with the write function, are there any other ways?

Comment: @DwikaHaryoRadithya I don’t fully get what you’re asking about, since the log approach that I discuss in my answer IS a txt file (in fact you could change `'log'` to `'my file.txt'`. An alternative I often use is the `pickle` module, which comes standard with Python, and is useful for storing of a whole Python object. In that case you wouldn’t have a human-readable file but you could always look at your stored data by `list_ = pickle.load('list-after-3-days.pickle')`

Comment: ^you’d have to `import pickle`. I’d google “Python pickle” if you’re interested in it

Comment: @ThomasBreydo aight thanks for the solution. FYI so what i meant was i used the built in write function to store the list in a txt file however because it is appended the txt file doesnt show or save the appended number or value, it only stores an empty list []. But thanks anyways huge help

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do what you are trying to do.

Let's first understand why your code is not working. Since Python does not pass by reference, when you are modifying `sum`, it won't affect your list. In fact Python does not pass by values either. ([You can dive more into this here](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference))

However you can use an object wrapper. Then the list will have an unchanged reference to the object. Finally you can modify the object.

```
class Sum:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

l = []
sum = Sum(data[0][1])
l.append(sum) 

sum.value = ...
```

Afterwards you can init your list of sums and update them.